# Laravel - Live version only works when debug = false

Tags: laravel

I've uploaded my page to my server and the login is not working, once I change

APP_DEBUG=true to false, the page is just not working anymore.

```
APP_NAME=MyPage
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:wFA/hKTOYzMeRyqNUbjJt-RiCmUxW70fxrtrqHPcOLI=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=https://www.mydomain.fake
```

The only thing I've changed was APP_DEBUG=true to false.

If it's true, I can login to my page on production and everything works just fine.
If it's false, I get this: `Whoops, something went wrong!` message

If I look at my logs live, I don't see any change.

Laravel Version: 5.5

PHP Version: 7.0.33

Comment: Check your laravel logs

Comment: like I said, I look at my logs live and there is no change.

Comment: I think you should change the value of `APP_ENV` to something else then `local`

Comment: Have your checked your Apache/PHP logs?

Comment: This is likely going to be difficult to provide help for, without any error messages or logs. It sounds like your application logic has some dependency on `APP_DEBUG = true`.